# Ajax and GridView-Fu -- how to make AccordionPanes work with GridViews?

Tags: gridview, asp.net-ajax

Ok, I know someone here has tried this ninja-elite level of coding before. Essentially what I want to do is this:

I want a GridView where each row returned becomes the header portion of an asp.net-ajax AccordionPane. Each row also has some unique key, and when you click on each of those AcccordionPane headers, that will in turn reveal the content pane which will then open up another GridView which is populated with the information from that is pulled from a database with that unique key.

Now I KNOW someone out there has tried something this insane --- and it doesn't seem to be that insanely hard, look in the cooments section from the poster named awni:

http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/video-87.aspx

```
<ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane2>
    <Header>
       **********EACH HEADER IS A ROW FROM A DATABASE 
    </Header>
    <Content>
        <asp:GridView  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
           **********THIS GRIDVIEW IS POPULATED WITH A DATABASE QUERY
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </Content>
</ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a ListView instead? I would think you could define the AccordianPanes in the ItemTemplate, then bind an inner GridView or ListView inside each row. The only downside would be that it would populate all Grid/ListViews on load.